# YouTube's Rewind feature of LiveStreams

Tags: youtube-live

Some live videos don't allow you to rewind at all, others the time which you can go back varies.

Is there a setting or something else that dictates whether you can rewind a live stream at all and for how long?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is an "Enable DVR" feature when starting a live video stream on the broadcaster end.

[Source](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/2853848?hl=en)

Comment: Add essential contents of the link into answer to make the answer more useful.